# Can't run docker image with XGBoost model(version 1.5.0)

Tags: python, docker, xgboost

I am apologizing, I am new to docker and my question might sound silly.
I have built a docker image and passed my trained model (XGBoost version 1.5.0).

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    rm requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
fastapi==0.70.0
uvicorn==0.15.0
scikit-learn==0.24.1
xgboost==1.5.0
```

When I build docker image everything works fine. But when I run `docker run --rm -p 80:80 project_dock:no-batch` I got the following lines:

```
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
```

and after that nothing happens. I tested the same main.py(server code) and Dockerfile code on other machine learning models(sklearn) and everything works well.

How can I fix it? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip3 with python version 3.X.+ you need to install like this:

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall pip==20.0.2
pip install xgboost==1.5.0
```

It will force install pip version 20, because the docker had issue with pip3.